# Vimeo iframe fullscreen issue on Firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe, vimeo, vimeo-player

When I fullscreen the Vimeo player on Firefox, the whole page becomes fullscreen instead of just the video. Any ideas why? I’ve been trying to look for the solution, but not many people have encountered this, apparently. The video is embedded using an iframe.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page? I've never seen this happen and I can't reproduce.

Comment: http://frontend-mfstaging.os1.delegated.net/ On the main page, in the bottom right corner there is a video “Meer Virginia”. It works in fullscreen on Firefox. However, the videos after you log in don’t. Use the credentials for logging in “rahul.jiresal@gmail.com” and password “1234”. After you log in, click on any course and start a video.

Comment: @BradDougherty, I still couldn’t figure out the problem. Were you able to reproduce it with the info I provided?

Comment: It looks like Firefox is preventing me from logging in because it's an insecure page. Is there anything different with the embed code logged in vs logged out?

Comment: No. The embed code is the same. I tried switching the videos. The one after logged in still has the problem.
By the way, What do you mean by insecure page? Try not using https to access the site.